# How do Nurseries make Pothos climb Moss pole?

Tags: moss, rooting-hormone

Friends, curious if you all know how Nurseries make Pothos climb the moss pole. I have tried this many times but have always been un-successful. Though I know how to take care of the Pothos and they generally do well at my place I have never been able to make a new plant root itself up the pole. Do they use rooting hormone ? If so, how ?

Awaiting your expert answers

Thanks.